How to Replace Acr.UserDialogs in a MAUI with WinUI3 Project?
I am migrating a Xamarin project with UWP to a .NET MAUI project with WinUI 3. In my Xamarin project, I used Acr.UserDialogs.IProgressDialog and Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.Alert for displaying progress dialogs and alerts. Since Acr.UserDialogs does not support platforms outside of Android, iOS, and UWP, I need to find an equivalent solution in MAUI with WinUI 3.
Here is my current UWP code:
using Acr.UserDialogs;

public class ImportDataForWin : IImportDataForWin
{
    private IProgressDialog progress;

    public async Task ImportData()
    {
        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker
        {
            ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
            SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
        };

        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xlsx");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xls");

        var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file != null)
        {
            var config = new ProgressDialogConfig()
                .SetTitle("Importing Data")
                .SetIsDeterministic(false);

            progress = UserDialogs.Instance.Progress(config);
            progress.PercentComplete = 0;
            progress.Show();

            // Some code
            var countMax = itemsToAdd.Count();
            var rowCount = 0;
            foreach (var item in itemsToAdd)
            {
                rowCount++;
                await SaveData(item);
                progress.PercentComplete = (rowCount * 100) / countMax;
            }
            progress.Hide();

            UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("errorMessage");
        }
    }
}

How can I achieve similar functionality in MAUI with WinUI 3?
Specifically, I need help with:
Displaying a progress dialog during the data import.
Showing an alert dialog when the import is complete or if there is an error.
Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Did you check the popup for the Maui?

Yes, I have looked into using popups in MAUI, but I'm not entirely sure how to implement them for showing progress dialogs and alerts. Could you provide an example or point me to some resources that demonstrate how to use popups for this purpose in a MAUI with WinUI 3 project?

I provided the sample code in my answer. You can check it.

Maui progress bar (with usage):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.progressbar?view=net-maui-8.0
Maui pop-ups ("alerts"; actions; prompts):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups?view=net-maui-8.0

Thank you for the suggestion! The MAUI pop-up works well when used in XAML.cs files(Page), but I'm encountering issues when trying to implement it in ViewModel.cs files. My ViewModel is inheriting from BaseViewModel. Any advice on how to handle this scenario would be greatly appreciated

I created a sample about displaying progress bar in the popup:
The code in the xaml:
toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.PopupTest">
    <VerticalStackLayout HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="200">
        <ProgressBar HeightRequest="50" Progress="{Binding Progress}" VerticalOptions="Center" ProgressColor="Red"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</toolkit:Popup>

The popup code in the class:
public partial class PopupTest : Popup, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     private double progress;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public double Progress
    {
        get => progress;
        set
        {
            if (progress != value)
            {
                progress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(); // reports this property
            }
        }
    }
    public PopupTest()
     {     
            InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "") =>
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
 
}

And display it in the contentpage:
var popup = new PopupTest();
this.ShowPopup(popup);

For more information, you can refer to the official document link I and Gerry Schmitz provided.
